# Prove that the set of diagonal matrices is a maximal torus of $U(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Let $G= U(n)$ be the unitary group. I want to understand the proof of the claim which say that

$$T=\left\lbrace\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\theta_1} & & & \\
 & e^{i\theta_2} & & \\
 & & \ddots & \\
 & & & e^{i\theta_n} \\
\end{pmatrix}, \theta_i \in \mathbb{R}\right\rbrace,
$$
is a maximal torus of $G$.

I was told that the proof of this claim is based on the fact that unitary matrices are diagonalizable and that a commuting set of diagonalizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable.

Suppose that $T$ is not maximal, i.e there exists a torus $H$ which strictly contains $T$. How to use the two facts to conclude that $T$ is a maximal torus ?

Comment: It's much easier..... assume that $A$ commutes with every elements in $T$, show that $A$ is also diagonal.

Comment: @asma With the approach you were suggested, I think it's easier to prove that every torus in $U(n)$ is isomorphic to a diagonal subgroup of $U(n)$. From there, it's easy to deduce that the maximal dimension of a torus of $G$ is $n$.